# Ionic Interval error - TypeError: fn is not a function

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, intervals

I need help with my app. I tried to refresh function every 5 seconds. Console shows "TypeError: fn is not a function". This is my code:

```
$scope.getItems = function (){ 
    $http.get('http://example.com/script.php')
       .success(function(res){
         $scope.news = res;
        })
       .error(function(data, status) {
          console.log("Error");
       })
       .finally(function(){
         $scope.$broadcast('scroll.refreshComplete');
       });
    }

    $scope.getItems();

    $interval($scope.getItems(), 5000);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For an interval, you have to pass the function, in this case your executing the function directly and pass the return value to $interval (which is undefined).

So change your code to this and it should work! :)

```
 $interval($scope.getItems, 5000);
```

Comment: i was writing this answer but you were faster :) this is the solution, this will works for sure

Comment: :D sorry for that, didn't mean to "steal" the answer here! :)